# Hadoop Cassandra CqlInputFormat pagination

Tags: hadoop, cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I am a quite newbie in Cassandra and have following question:

I have a 7-node Cassandra (v2.0.11) cluster and a table with 10k rows.
I run a hadoop job (datanodes reside on cassandra nodes of course) that reads data from that table and I see that only 7k rows is read to map phase.

I checked `CqlInputFormat` source code and noticed that a CQL query is build to select node-local date and also LIMIT clause is added (1k default). So that 7k read rows can be explained:
`7 nodes * 1k limit = 7k rows read total`

The limit can be changed using `CqlConfigHelper`:

```
CqlConfigHelper.setInputCQLPageRowSize(job.getConfiguration(), "1000");
```

**Please help me with questions below:** 
Is this a desired behavior? 
Why `CqlInputFormat` does not page through the rest of rows? 
Is it a bug or should I just increase the `InputCQLPageRowSize` value? 
What if I want to read all data in table and do not know the row count?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was related to a bug in cassandra 2.0.11 that added a strange LIMIT clause in underlying CQL query run to read data to the map task:

I posted that issue to cassandra jira: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-9074

It turned out that that problem was stricly related to the following bug fixed in cassandra 2.0.12: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-8166